# Auto-insert left bracket in Vim

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I'm trying to code some Objective-C in Vim and one thing I'm missing from Xcode is the ability to auto insert the left matching bracket.

Say if I have the following text:

```
NSString *string = [NSString alloc] init
```

and I insert ']' at the end of the row, then I want it to complete to:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] init]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a nice feature.

Apart from using [Surround](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697), I don't know of an exact solution.

With surround, starting with the cursor on the `t` of `init` in
 `NSString *string = [NSString alloc] init`:

1. `v` to enter visual mode
2. `F[` to select everything up to the first `[`
3. `s]` to surround it with `[]`

`vF[s]` can be tedious in the long run, in absence of a better/smarter solution you could make a dumb mapping like:

```
inoremap ]] vF[s]
```

Comment: That's a pretty neat solution. I'll accept that answer. Please note that it's capital S to surround it seems.

Comment: It depends on the version: in mine `s` and `S` are interchangeable for character-wise selection but different for line-wise selection.

Answer (score 3):

[This plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2558) might be what you're looking for. Haven't tried it out properly myself yet, but it seems to do the job.

> For instance, where `|` is the cursor:
>
> ```
> "foo|" becomes "[foo |]" after ] is pressed.
> "foo bar|" becomes "[foo bar]|"
> "foo: bar|" becomes "foo: [bar |]"
> "foo bar: baz|" becomes "[foo bar: baz]|"
> ```
>
> Certain useful keywords are also wrapped intelligently